# TNTSearch gives only one record, while algolia was giving 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

On my project, I had to use scout/searchable package and I got little problem.

scout/searchable package needs driver and I had two options. At first, I used Algolia, configured everything and made testing database with records

```
user_id / title / description


1      / title1 / descritpion1
2      / title2 / descritpion2
3      / title3 / descritpion3
4      / title4 / descritpion4
5      / title5 / descritpion5
```

when I used search method with algolia driver and searched for example title5 it gave me this result.
code:

```
Posts::search('title5')->get();
```

result:

```
1 / title5 / description5
2 / title1 / description1
3 / title2 / description2
4 / title3 / description3
5 / title4 / description4
```

but when I used TNTSearch it only gave me first record.
Why did this happen and how can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely this is the result of Algolia's built-in [typo tolerance](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/optimize-search-results/typo-tolerance/in-depth/configuring-typo-tolerance/) that also returns those similarly matching results, as each of those other results only differ by one character from the inputted search term.